# I trial make Notification for Comment

Tags: python, django, ajax, model

I trial make Notification for Comment

by Many-to-many relationships
how fix it
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use NotfFaId.set() instead.
[17/Apr/2021 03:37:31] "POST /forum/addcomment/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73061

```
class CommentT(MPTTModel):
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey( User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    NotfFaId = models.ManyToManyField( User, related_name='NotfFaVId', default=None, blank=True)
   
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['publish']



def addcomment(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    if request.POST.get('action') == 'delete':
        id = request.POST.get('nodeid') 
        c = CommentT.objects.get(id=id)
        c.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'remove': id})
    else:
        comment_form = NewCommentTForm(request.POST)
        # print(comment_form)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            user = request.user.username
            user_comment.author = request.user
            user_comment.NotfFaId = request.user
            user_comment.save()
            Topic.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('Topic') ).NotfFaV.add(request.user)
            # CommentT.objects.get(id=user_comment.id).NotfFaId.add(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user,'id': user_comment.id })
```

Comment: You should use more verbose names, it's not clear at all what "NotfFaId" is supposed for be. The error is pretty clear, use `user_comment.NotfFaId.set(request.user)` after saving your model

Comment: don't work , raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before ' ValueError: "<CommentT: CommentT object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: Call `user_comment.NotfFaId.set(request.user)` **after** `user_comment.save()`. You can't add many to many entries before you have saved both sides of the relationship

Answer (score 0):

don't work ,
raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
ValueError: "<CommentT: CommentT object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

```
def addcomment(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    if request.POST.get('action') == 'delete':
        id = request.POST.get('nodeid') 
        c = CommentT.objects.get(id=id)
        c.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'remove': id})
    else:
        comment_form = NewCommentTForm(request.POST)
        # print(comment_form)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            user = request.user.username
            user_comment.author = request.user

            user_comment.NotfFaId.set( request.user )

            user_comment.save()
            Topic.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('Topic') ).NotfFaV.add(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user,'id': user_comment.id })
```

Answer (score 0):

thank  Iain Shelvington,
it is word

I Called `CommentT.objects.get(id=user_comment.id).NotfFaId.add(request.user)` after `user_comment.save()`. You can't add many to many entries before you have saved both sides of the relationship – Iain Shelvington 2 hours ago

```
  def addcomment(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.POST.get('action') == 'delete':
            id = request.POST.get('nodeid') 
            c = CommentT.objects.get(id=id)
            c.delete()
            return JsonResponse({'remove': id})
        else:
            comment_form = NewCommentTForm(request.POST)
            # print(comment_form)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
                user = request.user.username
                user_comment.author = request.user
                # user_comment.NotfFaId.set( request.user )
                user_comment.save()
                Topic.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('Topic') ).NotfFaV.add(request.user)
                CommentT.objects.get(id=user_comment.id).NotfFaId.add(request.user)
                return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user,'id': user_comment.id })
```